# Finding the left-most child for every node in a tree in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, theory, graph-theory

[A paper](http://grantjenks.com/wiki/_media/ideas/simple_fast_algorithms_for_the_editing_distance_between_tree_and_related_problems.pdf) I am reading claims that

> It is easy to see that there is a linear time algorithm to compute the function `l()`

where `l()` gives the left-most child (both input and output are in postorder traversal of the tree). However, I can only think of a naive `O(n^2)` implementation where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree.

As an example, consider the following tree:

```
  a
 / \
c   b
```

In postorder traversal, the tree is `c b a`. The corresponding function `l()` should give `c b c`.

Here is my implementation in `O(n^2)` time.

```
public Object[] computeFunctionL(){
    ArrayList<String> l= new ArrayList<String>();
    l= l(this, l);
    return l.toArray();
}

private ArrayList<String> l(Node currentRoot, ArrayList<String> l){
    for (int i= 0; i < currentRoot.children.size(); i++){
        l= l(currentRoot.children.get(i), l);
    }
    while(currentRoot.children.size() != 0){
        currentRoot= currentRoot.children.get(0);
    }
    l.add(currentRoot.label);
    return l;
}
```

The tree is made as:

```
public class Node {
private String label;
private ArrayList<Node> children= new ArrayList<Node>();
...
```

Comment: How was the tree in question stored?

Comment: The paper claims there is a linear time algorithm in the first paragraph of page 8.

Comment: I think it's referring to finding the leftmost child of a given node? Isn't that essentially just "going left" from the current node until you reach a node which has no left child? That should be linear.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you provide an explicit algorithm as an answer please?

Comment: @Justin, yes it's linear only if you consider one node. But if you're calculating all of `l()`, it would be `O(n^2)`. Or perhaps you're saying that the paper refers to linear time only when consider one node (but it *would* be `O(n^2)` overall)?

Comment: @ijkilchenko Yes, from looking at the paper briefly, I think it's referring to a single node. And yes, it would still be O(n^2) overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple recursive algorithm you can use that can compute this information in O(1) time per node. Since there are n total nodes, this would run in O(n) total time.

The basic idea is the following recursive insight:

- For any node n with no left child, l(n) = n.
- Otherwise, if n has left child L, then l(n) = l(L).

This gives rise to this recursive algorithm, which annotates each node with its l value:

```
function computeL(node n) {
   if n is null, return.

   computeL(n.left)
   computeL(n.right)

   if n has no left child:
      set n.l = n
   else
      set n.l = n.left.l
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can find `l()` for the entire tree in less than O(n^2) time. The idea is to traverse the tree in order, maintaing a stack of the nodes you've visited while traversing the left branch. When you get to a leaf, that is the leftmost node for the entire branch.

Here's an example:

```
class BTreeNode
{
    public readonly int Value;
    public BTreeNode LeftChild { get; private set; }
    public BTreeNode RightChild { get; private set; }
}

void ShowLeftmost(BTreeNode node, Stack<int> stack)
{
    if (node.LeftChild == null)
    {
        // this is the leftmost node of every node on the stack
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var v = stack.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine("Leftmost node of {0} is {1}", v, node.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // push this value onto the stack so that
        // we can add its leftmost node when we find it.
        stack.Push(node.Value);
        ShowLeftmost(node.LeftChild, stack);
    }
    if (node.RightChild != null)
        ShowLeftmost(node.RightChild, stack);
}
```

The complexity is clearly not O(n^2). Rather, it's O(n).

It takes O(n) to traverse the tree. No node is placed on the stack more than once. The worst case for this algorithm is a tree that contains all left nodes. In that case it's O(n) to traverse the tree and O(n) to enumerate the stack. The best case is a tree that contains all right nodes, in which case there is never any stack to enumerate.

So O(n) time complexity, with O(n) worst case extra space for the stack.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, templatetypedef found an answer which doesn't even need a stack. Check it out.

Comment: @ijkilchenko: Yes, that works well if you can annotate the node.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at section 3.1:

> 3.1. Notation. Let T[i] be the ith node in the tree according to the left-to-right
>   postorder numbering, l(i) is the number of the leftmost leaf descendant of the subtree
>   rooted at T[i].

Given that sentence about notation, I would assume that the function l() is referring to finding a single node in linear time.

There may be a more elegant (better than O(n^2)) way of finding l() for an entire tree but I think it's referring to a single node.

Comment: There is an O(n log n) solution to find l() for the entire tree. See my answer.

Comment: Actually, finding l() for the entire tree is O(n).